# Criteria Class - Android Location - Why GPS provider is selected?

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I have a doubt on the selection algo for the getBestProvider method using a particular criteria.

When the Accuracy for bearing and speed is set to either medium, high or low; The GPS provider is selected by default as the best provider for the criteria which is fine since Network proivder does not  have any information related to these parameters.

However, even if I set the bearing accuracy or speed accuracy without enabling them (setting the parameters enabled field to true); always the GPS provider is called eventhough the bearing or speed wuld be returned as 0 since not enabled.

So in this case why not have the Network provider as the best provider instead since any way we are not going to have bearing or speed.

Will this have any implications on the battery life of the device if some one does try to use it since GPS would use more power than the Network Provider.

Short example:
criteriaobject.setBearingRequired (true);

criteriaobject.setBearingAccuracy (Criteria.LOW_ACCURACY);

locationmanagerobject.getBestProvider (criteriaobject, true); // Returns GPS which is fine

However;

criteriaobject.setBearingAccuracy (Criteria.LOW_ACCURACY);

locationmanagerobject.getBestProvider (criteriaobject, true); // Again returns GPS which does not make sense since the bearing is not enabled the location returned would not have bearing at all hence NETWORK seems to be the bestprovider but this is not how it works.

Any ideas or logical reasoning for this? Or if it would have any effects on the battery life of the device due to such implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) make it easier for developers to develop location-based apps. Just as the CoreLocation does in iOS, there is a single location provider than takes care of all your needs, no need to chose between GPS or another one...
see http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks; But I do not plan to use Google Services; Anyways the information was quite uesful. Also could you please elaborate on the difference between Accuracy and Horizontal Accuracy in the LocationPackage

Comment: According to the documentation, setHorizontalAccuracy() (API level 9+) is a more refined setAccuracy() (API level 1+), with a different set of constants. Both only control the horizontal accuracy level of requirement. I have to admit I have not tested the two methods comparatively...

Answer (score 0):

> So in this case why not have the Network provider as the best provider instead since any way we are not going to have bearing or speed.

Because you have nothing else in the `Criteria` that would steer the selection algorithm in the direction of using the network provider.

> Will this have any implications on the battery life of the device if some one does try to use it since GPS would use more power than the Network Provider.

If you care about power, [use `setPowerRequirement()` on `Criteria`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setPowerRequirement%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks; I know about these parameters but I just wanted to if only those 2 parameters are used with the others untouched what would be the impact. Anyways could you also elaborate on the difference between Accuracy and Horizontal Accuracy in the LocationPackage

Comment: @Rob, according to the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Criteria.java) they are the same. Doing `setAccuracy()` sets the horizontal accuracy. Then, in API 9, they added [`setVerticalAccuracy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setVerticalAccuracy(int)) and wanted to differentiate easier between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **bearing accuracy** => **NO_REQUIREMENT** then you will get **network** as a best provider

By setting **bearing accuracy** => **ACCURACY_LOW** instead of **ACCURACY_HIGH** will **speed** up the **location fix time**